PowerShell multiple sets of brace expansion?
Using the stock PS in W10 on a corporate desktop.
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                  
----                           -----                                                                                                                                  
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.4291                                                                                                                         
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.4291                                                                                                                        
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                        
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                    
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                    
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1 

In bash, one can easily expand multiple sets of variables at one time to make a long list.  This one, for example, generate 18 elements:
$ for s in FISP{CC,CDS,TAP}PGS{302,405}{a,b,c}; do ping -c3 $s; done
[bunch of ping output]

How does one do this in PowerShell?  The best I've come up with is this, which isn't so short.
foreach ($app in "CC","CDS","TAP") 
{ 
    foreach ($client in 302,405) 
    { 
        foreach ($node in "a","b","c") 
        { 
            $s="FISP${app}PGS${client}${Node}"
            ping $s
        } 
    } 
}


The way you're doing it in PowerShell is how it's done. Elegance is subjective, PowerShell code looks more elegant for me ;) You could use ForEach-Object as the outer loop and pipe all output to Test-Connection instead of having ping inside the loop

I've only done 1..100 | % tostring COMP000.

First build the array of names, then do the Test-Connection as suggested ( in the comments)
$ip=@()
foreach ($app in "CC","CDS","TAP") 
{ 
    foreach ($client in 302,405) 
    { 
        foreach ($node in "a","b","c") 
        { 
            $ip += "FISP${app}PGS${client}${Node}"
        } 
    } 
}
$ip | %{ $i=Test-Connection $_ -Count 1 -Quiet; $_, $i -join ' '}

output (on my system):
FISPCCPGS302a False
FISPCCPGS302b False
FISPCCPGS302c False
FISPCCPGS405a False
FISPCCPGS405b False
FISPCCPGS405c False
....


what I suggested was "CC","CDS","TAP" | ForEach-Object { .... } | Test-Connection, constructed strings can be piped directly to the cmdlet

@SantiagoSquarzon: I fail to see how to write this smarter (I am pretty new to PoswerShell too )
